# Solving Project Euler 1

Tags: clojure

I am trying to solve Project Euler problem in Clojure using recursion. The following is the problem statement:

> If we list all the natural numbers below 10 that are multiples of 3 or
>   5, we get 3, 5, 6 and 9. The sum of these multiples is 23.
>
> Find the sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below 1000.

However, the code below seems to give the wrong answer. What am I doing wrong?

```
(defn m?
  [x]
  (or (= (rem x 3)) (= (rem x 5))))

(defn sum-m
  [limit sum]
  (if (= limit  0)
    sum
    (recur (dec limit)
           (if (m? limit) 
             (+ sum limit)
             sum))))

(sum-m (dec 1000) 0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't say what erroneous answer it was giving, but I believe the problem is in m?:

```
(or (= 0 (rem x 3)) (= 0 (rem x 5)))
```

Answer (score 1):

m? change to

```
(defn m? [x]
  (or (zero? (rem x 3))(zero? (rem x 5))))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you wanted the function `m?` to check if a number is multiple of 3 or 5. But it does not do that. You should check if any of (rem x 3) or (rem x 5) are zero.

It's an interesting exercise to solve this for very large numbers. For example, find the sum of all the natural numbers below 1 billion that are multiples of 3 or 5. Your solution is linear in time, but you can try for a solution that is faster. This is not part of your original question; just an interesting addition to it.